# I have an error in my flask app. Invalid syntax at the second else

Tags: flask

```
if usernamedata is None:
            flash("No user named like this", "danger")
            return render_template("login/login.html")
        else:
            for passwor_data in passwordata:
                if sha256_crypt.verify(password, passwor_data):
                    flash("You are logged in", "success")
                    return redirect(url_for("home")
                else :
                    flash("dfgj", "danger")
                    return render_template("login/login.html")
    eturn render_template("login/login.html")
```

I have an error at the second else. Invalid syntax. How to rectify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `else` is not indented at same level of the initial `if` (see below an example of correct indentation).

**Your `redirect` at line 8 is missing the closing `)`.**

You have a typo in the final `return`.

```
if usernamedata is None:
    flash("No user named like this", "danger")
    return render_template("login/login.html")
else:
    for passwor_data in passwordata:
        if sha256_crypt.verify(password, passwor_data):
            flash("You are logged in", "success")
            return redirect(url_for("home"))  # close the parenthesis!
        else:
            flash("dfgj", "danger")
            return render_template("login/login.html")
return render_template("login/login.html")
```

More broadly speaking, you may want to follow a tutorial (an example [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-authentication-to-your-app-with-flask-login)) and rewrite your login function in a more reasonable way (from the above mentioned tutorial):

```
...
@auth.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_post():
    email = request.form.get('email')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    remember = True if request.form.get('remember') else False

    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

    # check if user actually exists
    # take the user supplied password, hash it, and compare it to the hashed password in database
    if not user or not check_password_hash(user.password, password):
        flash('Please check your login details and try again.')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login')) # if user doesn't exist or password is wrong, reload the page

    # if the above check passes, then we know the user has the right credentials
    return redirect(url_for('main.profile'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       if usernamedata is None:
            flash("No user named like this", "danger")
            return render_template("login/login.html")
        else:
            for passwor_data in passwordata:
                if sha256_crypt.verify(password, passwor_data):
                    flash("You are logged in", "success")
                    return redirect(url_for("home")
                else :
                    flash("dfgj", "danger")
                    return render_template("login/login.html")
        return render_template("login/login.html")
```

1. check indentation
2. typo error in return as eturn